# using html table and jquery with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of I am not HTML guy so apologies if this is very simple.
I purchased shared hosting last night and want to display html table on my webpage.
I also want to have the feature of sorting the html table. I did some googling and found tablesorter is good way to go.
I put my code here it is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\xx\Desktop\pages\jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 


$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

But the output it produces is

[image]

WHAT am i doing wrong here

Comment: place `$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 


$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
); ` these in script tag

Comment: also for some reason I feel like `<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\xx\Desktop\pages\jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>` won't work seeing as it's referring to YOUR desktop, not your hosting...

Comment: @guradio what you mean in script tag? Right now I am just trying on my desktop will put in shared hosting latter

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { $("#myTable").tablesorter(); } ); $(document).ready(function() { $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); } );</script>`

Answer (score 1):

This is corrected html for `tablesorter`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").tablesorter();
        $("#trigger-link").click(function () {
            var sorting = [[0, 0], [2, 0]];
            $("table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Last Name</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Email</th> 
            <th>Due</th> 
            <th>Web Site</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>John</td> 
            <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Bach</td> 
            <td>Frank</td> 
            <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Doe</td> 
            <td>Jason</td> 
            <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
            <td>$100.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Conway</td> 
            <td>Tim</td> 
            <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```